# Python check whether `datetime` is the beginning of the day?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For type `datetime.datetime`, how do we check whether the timestamp points to the beginning of the day?

The beginning of the day means the time `00:00:00.000000` of the day, while the date part can be anyone.

Comment: Get the hour, minute, and seconds from it and check if they're all 0.

Comment: This is going to to be fun if you have timezoned `datetime`s.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`datetime.time.min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.min) to get the earliest possible time (the beginning of the day) and compare it to [`your_datetime.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time)

```
your_datetime.time() == datetime.time.min
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will take care of it. In this example I am comparing with the current time. `datetime.time()` with no arguments is initialised to (0,0).

`datetime.time() == datetime.datetime.now().time()`